# Shadow on floor doesn't work in three.js v104 but works in r71

Tags: three.js, shadow

If you take a look here which is done with `r71` the shadows work:

```
var shadowlight = new THREE.DirectionalLight( 0xffffff, 1.8 );
shadowlight.position.set( 0, 100, 0 );
shadowlight.castShadow = true;
shadowlight.shadowDarkness = 0.1;
this.scene.add(shadowlight);

this.renderer.setClearColor( 0xf1c140, 1 );
this.renderer.shadowMapEnabled = true;
this.renderer.shadowMapType = THREE.PCFSoftShadowMap;
```

https://codepen.io/nicolasdnl/pen/VYRXWr

However, if I change the version to `104`, and make the necessary changes that it suggests:

> `.shadowMapEnabled is now .shadowMap.enabled.`
>
> `.shadowMapType is now .shadowMap.type.`
>
> `THREE.Light: .shadowDarkness has been removed.`

The shadow doesn't work any more: https://codepen.io/bertug48/pen/YMowKx

How to enable the shadows like r71 on v104?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`MeshBasicMaterial` is not able to receive shadows for over three years now. You have to use a lit material for your ground or add an additional ground mesh with an instance of [THREE.ShadowMaterial](https://threejs.org/docs/index.html#api/en/materials/ShadowMaterial).

Demo: https://jsfiddle.net/38weog40/

```
var planeGeometry = new THREE.PlaneGeometry( 200, 200 );
planeGeometry.rotateX( - Math.PI / 2 );

var planeMaterial = new THREE.ShadowMaterial();
planeMaterial.opacity = 0.2;

var plane = new THREE.Mesh( planeGeometry, planeMaterial );
plane.position.y = -200;
plane.receiveShadow = true;
scene.add( plane );
```

BTW: Here is the reason why `MeshBasicMaterial` does not receive shadows anymore: https://github.com/mrdoob/three.js/issues/8116#issuecomment-183540170

`three.js R104`

Comment: I understand. Is it too much to ask to show it in the codepen example? I'd be grateful